# Applications freeze and does not respond to mouse click or keyboard commands

Tags: keyboard, firefox, mouse, 15.04, bug-reporting

So yesterday I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop , it has 1.8 GiB RAM and 1.60GHz processor .

After a while when I was browsing on Firefox while it just stopped responding to the mouse clicks and I couldn't open Terminal or close the program using  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> but got no luck , I was able to move the cursor around but could not click anywhere so I had to shut down using the power button .

Till then I have encountered this problem many times and also with other programs . I have tried disabling and enabling proprietary drivers several times and downloading all updates and I have installed same version on another laptop and it also has the same problem.

Comment: Keep a terminal window open and run `top` in it. Watch the free memory and free swap count and try to reproduce the crash. It might be you're going out of memory.

Comment: well I don't know how to reproduce it, it just happens at times , sometimes after browsing for 4 minutes and sometimes after 1-2 hours , also when it happens  I cannot switch between tabs so I cannot check wether I am running out of memory or not.

Comment: You can right-click on the terminal window's title bar and select "always on top". Then you can lower its size to maybe 4 lines so that you only see the memory counter and place it somewhere in a corner of your screen. After doing this, wait for the crash and when it comes, note the free memory and swap values. Btw how big is your swap partition? [Edit] your question to add the output of `free -h` please.

Comment: well I don't have a swap partition and have all my memory in one disk . Yesterday I tried doing what you told , so I opened firefox ana created new tabs due to which my free memoy decreased to 180 MiB and noticed that firefox was using a lot of RAM ( even with only 2 tabs open it used almost 200 MiB )  , but even after this the crash didn't occur . Earlier today I installed chromium and it is showing a little better results ( as it hasn't frozen yet ) . I also freed up a lot of RAM using the following commands -    echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches   , and also echo2 and 3 .

Comment: after this I had almost 1200 MiB free space remainig and after sometime I encountered another crash when i was installing a programme using wine.   After the crash I pressed ctrl + alt + f1 ,  to open tty and there I used the top command and fount that I had almost 900 MiB RAM remaining . ( Sorry , I didn't read your reply till now so I didn't note the values at any time)  and I think there might be a problem with the graphic card , can that be the reason .     Thanks  for your support .

Comment: Except that I would recommend you to add at least 1-2 GB as swap and not to disable cache (this is dynamically allocated by Ubuntu to speed up disk access with the RAM not needed by software), I am out of ideas then. I hate graphics issues...

Comment: Well thanx for your help @ByteCommander

Comment: I have this problem as well. I'm generally able to save it by switching virtual desktops. Can you do that?  Either way, I recommend just downgrading to ubuntu 14.10. 15.04 has huge amounts of graphics problems.